# Versions of Trace Theorems

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I have a quick question about the Trace Theorem. I have been using Evans book of Partial Differential Equations to study Sobolev Spaces. The Trace Theorem is given as "If $U$ is bounded and $\partial U$ is $C^{1}$ then there exists a bounded linear functional $T: W^{1,p}(U) \rightarrow L^{p}(\partial U)$". In a different book the Trace Theorem is given such that there is a trace operator $u \mapsto u |_{\Gamma}$ maps $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ into $L^{p^{\text#}}(\Gamma)$. Where $p^{\text #} := \{ \frac{np-p}{n-p} \text{ for } p=n ; \text{ an arbitrary large constant for $p=n$}; +\infty \text{ for } p > n \}$. How do these two Theorems coincide? What is the standard theorem?

Comment: The sharp form of the trace theorem embeds into a certain Besov space on the boundary, see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/70740/image-of-the-trace-operator Rather trivially this Besov space is a subspace of $L^p$. That it is a subspace of $L^{p^\sharp}$ is probably some version of Sobolev embedding.

Comment: In terms of scaling, dropping one dimension you need to lose $1/p$ derivatives. Observing that $(np-p)/(n-p) = (n-1)p / (n-1+1 - p)$ this is commensurate with the scaling for Sobolev embedding on the boundary (which has dimension $n-1$).

Comment: Thanks I am revising the link that you made available. Can I ask you a different question based on a book I am using? Is it possible to go into chat for a second?

Comment: If you have another question, feel free to post it as such: this way more people can help you.

Comment: Okay but I doubt anyone will take the time to revise the question. It will require some attachments. It is regarding using Monotone Operators to solve 2nd order PDE's, there is obviously some Sobolev Space stuff as well.

Comment: I posted the question under 'Weak continuity of Sobolev Spaces'